# cPanel cron giving /bin/bash: 1@reboot: ambiguous redirect

Tags: apache-http-server, cron, cpanel

Cron  /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/bin/dnsqueue > /dev/null 2>&1@reboot /usr/local/cpanel/bin/onboot_handler

Giving report: /bin/bash: 1@reboot: ambiguous redirect

I would like know what does it means and if there any issue with this report?

This cron generated often.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have an error in your crontab. The line should end after the `1`, and the `@reboot` should be on a new line.

Comment: Thanks for your response, would you please explain what purpose actually using this cron and whats affecting?